Сравнительный ли это оборот?
"Я иногда думаю, что нигде в мире нет такой разнообразной жизни, как у нас на Руси"
"Как у нас на Руси" — это что? Сравнительный оборот? Придаточное сравнения?

А чем сравнительный оборот отличается от придаточного сравнения?

Я иногда думаю, что нигде в мире нет такой разнообразной жизни, как у нас на Руси.

Это сравнительный оборот, информация есть у Розенталя, пункт 3(2)

Пункт 3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:
2) если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово (так, такой, тот, столь): Редко встречаешь столь интересного человека, как он. Ямщик был в таком же изумлении от его щедрости, как и сам француз от предложения Дубровского (П.);

Сравнительный оборот – полупредикативная конструкция, в нем нет сказуемого, как в сравнительном придаточном.

Например: Я иногда думаю, что нигде в мире нет такой разнообразной жизни, какая  есть у нас на Руси.
